# AngularJs routing issue with <a> tag

Tags: angularjs

I am beginner in Angular please give me an answer.

Why do we need to add `#!` in href attribute? Otherwise it will not work as expected in navigating the file in SPA.

```
<a class="nav-link active" href="#!add">Add Post</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this syntax.
For Angular links, I use `routerLink` :

```
<a class="nav-link active" routerLink="/add">Add Post</a>
```